# OpenTK 2.0.0 error with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, nuget-package, opentk

I'm trying to add the OpenTK v2.0.0 package to my project.

If I create a project of type "Class Library (.NET Framework)" and I add OpenTK v2.0.0 using the "Manage Package for Solution", everything works well.

If I create a project of type "Class Library (.NET Standard)" and I add OpenTK v2.0.0 using the "Manage Package for Solution", I get the following error:

> Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'ClassLibrary1'.

I get an error also if I download OpenTK library and I try to add using "Add Reference". With the first project type it works, with the second when I try to refer to a class (e.g declaring a Vector2d variable) I get the following error:

> CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an
>   assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly...

I'm not really understanding why. Is there substantial difference between the 2 project type, and why the second type does not get the reference and break the package manager?

Thanks a lot.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to OpenTK targetting [.NET Framework 2.0](https://github.com/opentk/opentk/blob/2.0-0/src/OpenTK/OpenTK.csproj#L17), which means that it can be used in projects targetting the .NET Framework (windows only). If you're creating a project targetting .NET Standard (cross-platform), you can't currently use OpenTK 2.0.0.

However, there are already [forks](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ppy.OpenTK.NS20/) of OpenTK that target .NET Standard, and the official version 4.0 of OpenTK will support [.NET Standard](https://github.com/opentk/opentk/issues/245). You might have to wait a bit for that one though.